# Laravel routes not displaying error when required params missing

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.4

I have some weirdness with Laravel at the moment and can't figure out what's wrong

If i don't include a parameter in the url, my controller should redirect but it doesn't.  I've tried dumping out some text but all I get it is a plain white screen unless I include the param in the url.  The param is set to optional.  Even if I remove the `?` to make the param madatory, I still get a white screen where I would expect some sort of error.

The rest of the routes work fine apart from the route group in question.

Here is a cut down version of my controller

```
class CustomerRequirementsController extends Controller
{
    public function index($id = '')
    {
        debug('sdfgsdfgdsg');
        exit;
        //if the id has been removed from the url, redirect back to quotes summary table
        if(empty($id)) {
            return redirect()->route('quote.index');
        }
        ...
    }
```

Here is my routes in question

```
Route::prefix('quotes')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/{id?}', 'QuoteController@show')->name('quote.show');

    Route::post('/customer-requirements/add-group', 'CustomerRequirementsController@ajax')->name('customer-requirements.add-group');
    Route::get('/customer-requirements/{id?}', 'CustomerRequirementsController@index')->name('quote.customer-requirements.index');
    Route::resource('/customer-requirements', 'CustomerRequirementsController', ['except' => ['show', 'destroy']]);
```

Comment: does it print any 'sdfgsdfgdsg' when you debug this?

Comment: ehhmmm you exit your script in an early stage

Comment: What does `storage/logs/laravel.log` say?

Comment: i think he is only debugging in first 2 lines of index function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same problem before.

Your first route `Route::get('/{id?}', 'QuoteController@show')->name('quote.show');` is getting called before any other route.

Does your show function return a view....or anything? If it does, try moving to the bottom of the route group

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making {id?} optional you make it compulsory by {id} may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a logical error, your `if` is never true because your `$id` param is never empty, it has assigned value always, in this case if it's not present in the url, it's assigned value is `''` which fails `empty` check. So you would be better off if you `$id = null` and then `if(is_null($id))`

Answer (score 0):

### Laravel & Nginx :

If you are using virtual host add this line on vhost conf.

```
location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Know More : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4#web-server-configuration